# Fatal error: Class 'Camiloo_Amazonimport_Helper_Data' not found in /home/drwakde1/public_html/eshop/app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: php, magento, integration

I am new to Magento. I just installed Camiloo Global Amazon Integration 2.4.1.0, as soon as I installed it, I am not able to login to my Magento admin. When I enter the login id and password in the admin area, it displays the following error -

> Fatal error: Class 'Camiloo_Amazonimport_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /home/drwakde1/public_html/eshop/app/Mage.php on line 547

I would appreciate your help.
Many thanks,
Nilesh

Comment: We do not have enough information to do anything for you here. Possibilities: 1) you did not install it correctly. 2) the module is incompatible. 3) the module is simply broken.

Answer (score 0):

check if `app/code/{local or community}/Camiloo/Amazonimport/Helper/Data.php` exits? If not, check your module if it has or not. If not, then simply create a file `Data.php` under above mentioned path and paste the following code in it:

```
class Camiloo_Amazonimport_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```